# Woocommerce single product add to cart button not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I have developed a custom theme. Everything working fine but woocommerce single product page add to cart button not updating products.

In the cart page update cart works sometimes and again suddenly stop working. here is the link http://webdesign-projects.xyz/mer/shop

Can anyone figure out the issue?

Comment: You have too many "cheap" plugins enabled and may be one of them is certainly disabling the click event through javascript with something like `event.preventDefault()` … So you should try to disable them one by one to see which one is involved. This can also come from theme customizations. Now your question is off-topic on StackOverFlow as it doesn't involve any programing code directly…

Comment: I have checked disabling all of my plugins. But no luck.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. I deactivated all plugins but no luck. Finally, I checked the scripts that I added in my theme js folder. After deleted "image-scale.js" file my website start working perfectly.

My suggestion, don't put unauthorized ajax related js plugin with the theme.

Comment: So I was right… **that was related javascript**. You can add JS, but you need to test everything to be sure that there is no issues.